Non-negativity constraints in linear-programming formulation of $L_1$ norm minimization
My goal is to solve the following minimization problem:
$$
\min_{x}|Ax - b|_1 \tag{1},
$$
where, for simplicity, $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and $x,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. One can solve this by expressing it as a linear programming problem as follows. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and solve instead the following
$$
\min_{x,y} (0\cdot x + 1 \cdot y)
$$
subject to
$$
y \geq Ax - b, \quad y \geq -(Ax-b),
$$
which can be written as a linear constraint as follows
$$
\begin{pmatrix}A & -I\\-A & -I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} \leq \begin{pmatrix}b\\-b\end{pmatrix}.
$$
My question concerns the non-negativity constraints on $(x,y)$. It is clear that the conditions $y \geq Ax - b, y \geq -(Ax-b)$ imply that $y \geq 0$. My question is: how does one derive that $x \geq 0$? I've seen the argument made that: since changes in $x$ do not modify the cost function value, we can impose any constraint on $x$, and therefore, we can just assert that $x \geq 0$.
I don't fully understand this argument. I could alternatively write the cost function as
$$
\min_x \min_y 1 \cdot y.
$$
Since the constraints on $y$ are functions of $x$, it seems to me that $\min_y y$ is itself also a function of $x$ since fixing a value $x_0$ of $x$ would yield a different lower bound $y \geq |Ax_0 - b|$ for $y$ to satisfy. Therefore, how can I make the claim that $x \geq 0$? It also seems that, if $x \geq 0$ for the linear programming problem, then its also true that the minimizer for Eq. (1) can also be chosen to be $\geq 0$, and its unclear to me what the justification for that is.

There are several formulations for linear programming problems which are all equivalent in that the feasibility and the optimal are the same. One of them does not necessitate the non negativity of the variables. Anyway, the tranformation you are looking for is the following : create two vectors of new non negative variables $x^+$ and $x^-$. Add the constraint $x = x^+-x^-$ and write everything with $x^+$ and $x^-$.

You cannot derive $x\ge0$, and actually you do not need it for solving the model using general LP solvers.
If you personaly want to solve the model by the simplex method (in which all variables need to be non-negative, and all constraints need to be equality constraints), you need to consider the following change of variables
$$x=x^+-x^-,x^+,x^- \ge 0, \color{red}{x^+_i\times x^-_i=0, i=1,\dots,n },$$
and add a vector of slack variables $s\ge 0$ to have equality constraint
$$
\begin{pmatrix}A & -I\\-A & -I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x^+-x^-\\y\end{pmatrix} +\text{I}s= \begin{pmatrix}b\\-b\end{pmatrix}.
$$
However, fortunately we can drop the red nonlinear part when using the simplex method. The reason is that for each $i$, the columns of two variables $\color{red}{x^+_i,x^-_i}$ in the constraints are dependent and thus both variables cannot appear simultaneously in any base used in any iteration of the simplex method, so at least one of $x^+_i,x^-_i$  is out of the base and it's value is zero, automatically guranteeing that $x^+_i\times x^-_i=0$.
Again, recall that we only need this change of variables (and converting all the constraints to equality constraints) if we want to solve the model by the simplex method as other methods such as interior point methods generally do not require to work with non-negative variables.

It is not necessarily true that $x \ge 0$.  Consider the one-dimensional example  of minimizing $|x+1|$.  That is, $n=1$, $A=(1)$, and $b=-1$.  The unique optimal solution is $x=-1$, and the corresponding LP has unique optimal solution $(x,y)=(-1,1)$.
